# calling parent class method from child class object in java

Tags: java

I have a parent class which has a method, in the child class I override that parent class's method. In a third class I make an object of child and by using that object I want call the method of parent class. Is it possible to call that parent class method ? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 41):

If you override a parent method in its child, child objects will always use the overridden version. But; you can use the keyword `super` to call the parent method, **inside the body of the child method**.

```
public class PolyTest{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Child().foo();
    }

}
class Parent{
    public void foo(){
        System.out.println("I'm the parent.");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    @Override
    public void foo(){
        //super.foo();
        System.out.println("I'm the child.");
    }
}
```

This would print:

> I'm the child.

Uncomment the commented line and it would print:

> I'm the parent.
>
> I'm the child.

You should look for the concept of Polymorphism.

Answer (score 11):

Use the keyword **super** within the overridden method in the child class to use the parent class method. You can only use the keyword within the overridden method though. The example below will help.

```
public class Parent {
    public int add(int m, int n){
        return m+n;
    }
}


public class Child extends Parent{
    public int add(int m,int n,int o){
        return super.add(super.add(m, n),0);
    }

}


public class SimpleInheritanceTest {
    public static void main(String[] a){
        Child child = new Child();
        child.add(10, 11);
    }
}
```

The `add` method in the Child class calls `super.add` to reuse the addition logic.

Comment: Isn't "@Override" required for Child's add()?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it is a bad design, if you need something like that, it is good idea to refactor, e.g. by renaming the method.
[Java allows calling of overriden method using the "super" keyword](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html), but only one level up in the hierarchy, I am not sure, maybe Scala and some other JVM languages support it for any level.

Comment: A legitimate use case is within some instrumentation frameworks, e.g. Frida

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE** calling parent method via super will only work on parent class,
If your parent is interface, and wants to call the default methods then need to add interfaceName before super like `IfscName.super.method();`

```
interface Vehicle {
    //Non abstract method
    public default void printVehicleTypeName() { //default keyword can be used only in interface.
        System.out.println("Vehicle");
    }
}


class FordFigo extends FordImpl implements Vehicle, Ford {
    @Override
    public void printVehicleTypeName() { 
        System.out.println("Figo");
        Vehicle.super.printVehicleTypeName();
    }
}
```

Interface name is needed because same default methods can be available in multiple interface name that this class extends. So explicit call to a method is required.

Answer (score 1):

Say the hierarchy is `C->B->A` with A being the base class.

I think there's more to fixing this than renaming a method.  That will *work* but is that a fix?

One way is to refactor all the functionality common to B and C into D, and let B and C inherit from D:  `(B,C)->D->A`  Now the method in B that was hiding A's implementation from C is specific to B and stays there.  This allows C to invoke the method in A without any hokery.