# How do i keep trace of a super class attribute in a subclass that modifies this attribute?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have these two classes Order and ValidatedOrder. ValidatedOrder is a subclass of order in which we specify the ID of the assistant that validated the order and the reduction that he may apply on the final price. However I want to keep trace of the old price that will be inherited from the super class. 
This is the Order Class :

```
public class Commande {
private int idCommande;
private int idClient ;
private String Commentaire; 
private ArrayList<LigneCommande> Liste ;

public double calculMontantCommande(){
    int i ;
    for (i=0; i<this.getListe().size();i++){
        montant= montant + (Liste.get(i).getMontantCommande() * Liste.get(i).getQuantiteCommande());
    }

    return montant ;

}
```

This is the ValidatedOrder Class :

```
public class CommandeValidee extends Commande {
private int Assistant ; 
private Double reduction ;


@Override
public double calculMontantCommande() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (super.calculMontantCommande() * reduction);

}
```

Any clues on how to solve this will be great ! 
Thanks

Comment: What do you actually mean by "*keep trace*"?

Comment: create a variable and whenever you change the value keep it on the old value on that variable. but i think you understand iheritance the wrong way you talk that you mean that command and validat command are two separate thing ?!!

Comment: Hope this will help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3797265/5617860

Comment: Don't have a second price. Have a discount field. NB Don't **ever** use floating point for money. These amounts should all be `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
super.calculMontantCommande()
```

Returns the "old price" (the price without reduction).

So in your `CommandeValidee` class you can add a method like this

```
public double getPriceWithoutReduction() {
    return super.calculMontantCommande();

}
```

and then you can get it by calling this method

```
CommandeValidee order =  ... //Load somehow
double priceWithoutReduction = order.getPriceWithoutReduction();
```

Anyway, I suggest you to use english when developing an application. That's because most of the library and code you will use (the language itself) is written in english. It's also a problem for people like us to help you if the class and method names aren't written in english. Imagine if it was written in chinese :D

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I usually write code in english but sorry i'm in France right now ! :D